# Sharing a session store on Redis for a Django and a Express.js Application

Tags: python, django, node.js, redis, express

I want to create a Django application with some logged-in users. On another side, since I want some real-time capabilities, I want to use an Express.js application.

Now, the problem is, I don't want unauthentified users to access Express.js application's datas. So I have to share a session store between the Express.js and the Django applications.

I thought using Redis would be a good idea, since the volatile keys are perfect for this fit, and I already use Redis for another part of the application.

On the Express.js application, I'd have this kind of code :

```
[...]
this.sessionStore = new RedisStore;
this.use(express.session({
  // Private crypting key
  secret: 'keyboard cat', // I'm worried about this for session sharing
  store: this.sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1800000
  }
}))
[...]
```

On the Django side, I'd think of using the [django-redis-session](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions) app.

So, is this a good idea? Won't there be any problem? Especially about the secret key, I'm not sure they will both share the same sessions.

Comment: You definitely will have to write a custom handler for either express or django, to sync how they encode the cookie, how they map the session identifier in the cookie to the redis key, and how they map the redis value to a session.

Comment: Heh, so there is no way to have it working out of the box? I'd like to have the opinion of someone having worked with both systems (maybe you have, I don't know :)).

Comment: Of course, you don't have to trust me. I have never worked with django-redis-session. But I have worked a lot with Express and Django. But that's neither here nor there, because it's a fact that Express sessions are JSON, and Django sessions are pickled Python objects. So that won't work. Express stores sessions as `sess:sessionId`, and it's not a wild guess that django-redis-session uses some other scheme to map between redis keys and session ids.

Comment: Alright, that's the kind of answer I expected (explaining why it wouldn't work). If you're adding this as an answer, I'll give it to you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a custom session store for either Express or Django. Django, by default (as well as in django-redis-sessions) stores sessions as pickled Python objects. Express stores sessions as JSON strings. Express, with connect-redis, stores sessions under the key `sess:sessionId` in redis, while Django (not totally sure about this) seems to store them under the key `sessionId`. You might be able to use django-redis-sessions as a base, and override `encode`, `decode`, `_get_session_key`, `_set_session_key` and perhaps a few others. You would also have to make sure that cookies are stored and encrypted in the same way.

Obviously, it will be way harder to create a session store for Express that can pickle and unpickle Python objects.

Comment: Actually, you can serialize Django sessions in JSON format since Django 1.5.3. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization